# Estimating the value of this Integral

Tags: integration, area, estimation

> If I=$\int_0^1x^{sinx+cosx}dx$ then find the value of $[10I]$ where $[.]$ represent greatest integer function.
>
> A)3
>
> $\boxed{B)4}$
>
> C)5
>
> D)6
>
> Mathongo, JEE sample questions

**Method 1**: I took a few points on the given curve and estimated out the area to be slightly less than 0.5 in the given interval, thus yielding the correct answer: 4.

[image]

**Legend:**

1. Black line $y=x$
2. Curve bordering red area $x^{\sin x + \cos x}$
3. Bounds as given.

Here is the attached [Desmos link](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/66lrvvpqxi)  to depict the same

**Method 2** (prompted):

$\hspace{42px} 1\leq sinx+cosx \leq \sqrt{2}$

$\implies x \geq x^{sinx+cosx} \geq x^{\sqrt{2}}$

$\implies \int_0^1 xdx \geq \int_0^1x^{sinx+cosx}dx \geq \int_0^1x^{\sqrt{2}}dx$

$\implies 0.5 \geq I \geq 0.414$

Thus, $\boxed{[10I]=4}$.

Would be glad if the community could come up with more alternative approaches.

Comment: Source of the question? But I think your idea is more or less the ideal way of solving

Comment: Impressed by the effort you put into writing this question. I have edited and give you a +1.

Comment: I agree. Always good to have multiple ways of solving.

Comment: The inequalities on the integrals in Method 2 are strict ($<$) because $\sin x+\cos x$ is not constant. You need this to get a strict inequality $0.5>I$ so that $5>10I.$

Comment: @Beautifullyirrational The question appeared in one of my mock exams for the engineering entrance exam, JEE-Mains, of our country.

Comment: Ah I see. I suggest adding the date and shift under question if you know it. BTW I think we've met before, buraian here ( discord).

Comment: Oh it was from Mathongo mock for jee and not the actual jee (i think u misunderstood). So, there's no shift thing required to be mentioned. Also, yeah- I think we met at jee pro (m the same arsenic guy). Good to see ya! If you want, we could get into touch on discord.

Answer (score 4):

Your solution is nice and simple.

*On purpose*, I shall make a  complex one.

Consider
$$y=x^{\sin (x)+\cos (x)}\quad \implies \quad \log(y)=[\sin (x)+\cos (x)]\log(x)$$ that is to say
$$\log(y)=\log(x) \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\sin \left(\frac{\pi  n}{2}\right)+\cos \left(\frac{\pi  n}{2}\right)}{n!} x^n$$ Truncate to some order $m$ and use
$$y=e^{\log(y)}$$ This will give
$$y=\sum_{n=1}^m \frac{P_n} {(n-1)!} x^n$$ where the $P_n$ are polynomials of degree $(n-1)$ in $\log(x)$ with no constant term. Using $L=\log(x)$, the first polynomials are
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & P_n \\
 1 & 1 \\
 2 & L \\
 3 & L^2-L \\
 4 & L^3-3 L^2-L \\
 5 & L^4-6 L^3-L^2+L 
\end{array}
\right)$$

Now, we shall use the fact that, for positive $(p,q)$
$$\int_0^1 x^p \,\log ^q(x)\,dx=(-1)^q  \frac {q!}{(p+1)^{q+1} }$$ Using all the above, we can now compute exactly the result for the successive values of $m$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
m & \text{result} \\
 1 & \frac{1}{2} \\
 2 & \frac{7}{18} \\
 3 & \frac{251}{576} \\
 4 & \frac{155819}{360000} \\
 5 & \frac{4204613}{9720000} 
\end{array}
\right)$$

As soon as $m\geq 3$, you have the result.

If the problem was $\lfloor 100 I\rfloor$, as soon as $m\geq 3$, you would have $43$. If it was $\lfloor 1000 I\rfloor$, as soon as $m\geq 4$, you would have $432$.

Comment: It would have been really useful to me if I knew what actually was going on here. I mean I can make out what the approach is, but I am limited by my knowledge in this topic. Regardless, thanks for your time and efforts! Not marking this as solution though, as I still am looking for alternatives within the limits of high school mathematics.

Comment: How did you arrive at the integral result you plugged in? Can I get a link to reference or an explanation here, if possible? Another query, is there a way to derive this kind of relation for trigonometric functions as well? Say for example: $\int_0^1x^psin^qxdx$

Comment: Concerning your first comment : I wrote that my intent was to make it complex (on purpose). For the second comment, using the Taylor series and binomial expansion makes the problem simple. But, don't worry : you will learn all of that very soon. Good luck in your studies. Cheers :-)